# How to return a 401 error with Adonis' websocket middleware

Tags: websocket, middleware, adonis.js

I’m building a websocket middleware and I want to return a 401 from it.

This is my code:

```
async wsHandle({ request, response }, next) {


    let token =request.only('token').token;

    await axios.get('auth server url', {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': token,
      },
    })
      .then(async (response) => {
        await next();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        if (err.response) {
          let err_code = err.response.status.toString()
          //This response can't return responses.
          response.status(err_code).send(err.response.data.message)
        }
      });
  }
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Question solved by Harminder Virk : https://forum.adonisjs.com/t/use-websocket-middleware-return-response-401/4473

Answer :

You cannot make standard `response` with HTTP status codes in websocket connections.

Simply throw an exception from the middleware and AdonisJs will send that error to the channel `on('error')` event listener on the client.